# Android API to check if the CPU is slowed down

Tags: android

I have built an Android App that does not require a high-performance CPU.
During the tests, it appeared that once, the app got slowed down (1-2 seconds to respond to a click).
I suspect an overheating issue as the tablet is protected by a foam cover and was in the bright sun for hours.

Is there an API I could use to get notified when the CPU speed is reduced to avoid overheating?

Comment: It looks like you might be able to get the information from here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HardwarePropertiesManager I'm not exactly known for my Android development skills, but it looks like you can check if TEMPERATURE_CURRENT > TEMPERATURE_THROTTLING

Comment: This is a possibility, but I would prefer to get notified rather than having to poll for the temperature.

Comment: It would certainly be more convenient, but it doesn't look like Android exposes an on handler for CPU throttling.

Comment: Yes this is maybe why I did not found this handler :-)
I will check What I can do with this HardwarePropertiesManager.
Thanks for pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getDeviceTemperature()** method in **HardwarePropertyManager** class get current cpu temperature and the cpu throttling temperature. Then by comparing the two you could know if the cpu slowed down due to overheating.Checkout the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HardwarePropertiesManager#DEVICE_TEMPERATURE_CPU

Comment: Thanks for the link. This gives the CPU frequency. But we don't know why the frequency is lowered. It could be just because the CPUs have nothing to do.

Comment: If you want to know cpu temperature this could help you. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HardwarePropertiesManager.html#DEVICE_TEMPERATURE_CPU

Comment: HardwarePropertyManager is accessible to VR service or Device Owner applications only. Android Documentation says: "
if something other than the device owner or the current VR service tries to retrieve information provided by this service."